# History.pushState URL + Scroll To Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm changing my sites URLs to /name using History.pushState, which is working but the page does not scroll to the location of the site it is suppose to.

**index.php:**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li>Blog <!-- Coming Soon... --> </li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<article class="content" id="work"> 
...

<article class="content" id="about">
...
```

**jquery.page.js:**

```
_saveState = function( chapter ) {

    if (History.getState().url.queryStringToJSON().chapter !== chapter) {
        var page;

        if (chapter == 1)
            page = "/work";

        if (chapter == 2)
            page = "/about";

        if (chapter == 3)
            page = "/services";

        if (chapter == 4)
            page = "/blog";

        if (chapter == 5)
            page = "/contact";

        else 
            page = '?chapter=' + chapter;

        History.pushState(null, null, page)
    }
},

...

_goto = function( chapter ) {

    var chapter = chapter || History.getState().url.queryStringToJSON().chapter,
    isHome = ( chapter === undefined ),

    $article    = $( chapter ? '#' + 'chapter' + chapter : '#' + 'introduction' );

...
```

When the user clicks on a link in the navigation menu, how do I make the page jump to the location it is suppose to, as seen in the **[tutorial](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/02/responsive-horizontal-layout/)** I've been following?

Comment: i saw your website with the code implemented i debugged the code and i found that the left position is always zero that's why its not scrolling to left i think you have to align all the articles to the left may be you can hardcode the width of the content-scroller say about 9000px or above

Comment: their is no problem in your javascript its prefect but the problem was in your html please correct the content-wrapper div it was not enclosing the articles it was like <div class="content-wrapper"></div><article></article>....it should be  <div class="content-wrapper"><article></article>...</div>

Comment: * facepalm*.  Thank you fuzionpro, amazing observation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`History.getState().url.queryStringToJSON().chapter` is trying to find a query parameter `chapter` in your URL, which doesn’t exist anymore since you changed the URL format.

Without having worked with $.History, it seems to me that you could try to compare against the URL, using something along the lines of:

```
if (History.getState().hash.replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '') !== chapter) { ... }
// replace(/^\/|\/$/g, '') will remove a leading and/or trailing slash '/'
```

Note though, that if your site does not live on the root (e.g. `http://example.com/foo/bar/portfolio`) you’ll still have to deal with the rest of the URL, since `History.getState().hash` will return you `/foo/bar/portfolio` instead of `/portfolio`.

*(On a side note: If you find yourself writing repeatedly `else if`, try using a [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) instead.)*

Comment: I’m not in the clear how you have updated the code from the tutorial already, but have a look at this — http://pastebin.com/22FrJiS1 , seems to pretty much do what you want? Have a look at the changes in `._initMenuEvents`, `._initArticleEvents`, `._goto` and `._saveState`. Try to incorporate these into your solution.

Comment: It seems to me that scrolling works and the page appears to transition for a few pixels as well. Are you sure that all your CSS in order? This case is very hard to debug from the distance. Especially since you’re using “real” URLs instead of hashes, so every time I refresh the page after clicking a link I will get a 404 (have you considered this issue btw.?).

Comment: Btw., why is `._initArticleEvents` returning `true` in your case?

Comment: Hi polarblau, I've had a look into both my css and html files and it seems I hadn't commented out a small section I was supposed to (an ending `</div>` tag to be precise). The site is now working perfectly thanks to both you and fuzionpro. I know what you mean by refreshing the page and getting an error, which I'm guessing I'll have to create another thread on to solve this? In terms of setting my `_initArticleEvents` to return as `true`, instead of what's mentioned in the tutorial, will allow me to use external links on the website (weird huh?). Anyway...A BIG THANK U ON YOUR INCREDIBLE HELP!

Answer (score 3):

their is no problem in your javascript its prefect but the problem was in your html please correct the content-wrapper div it was not enclosing the articles it was like

```
<div class="content-wrapper"></div><article></article>...
```

it should be

```
<div class="content-wrapper"><article></article>....</div>
```

Comment: This response is a contributing answer to my question/problem...but I don't have enough reputation points to up-vote it.  thank you fuzionpro.